# Validation of username with Django authenticate

Tags: django, authentication

I am currently building a django app. I have a form where the user input his/her data for registration. I use the User table (of django.contrib.auth.models) and I also have a UserProfile table where I store additional information. My question is how would I validate (no special character, no spaces, etc) the username that I send to:

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user( username, email, password)
```

I am using a form from the UserProfile model. I try to validate my form with: 
form.is_valid():

But as the User field is a foreign key, it  is transformed into a multiplechoice field, so it doesn't validate unless the user is already present in the User table.

So how could I validate the username before calling

```
User.objects.create_user( username, email, password)
```

In my experience, create_user allows anything as username.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a method to your form:

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    # do whatever checks you want and raise `ValidationError` if there's an issue
    return username
```